# Mailchimp subscription form integration

Tags: drupal-7, mailchimp

I want to add a mailchimp subscription form my drupal site to allow users to subscribe for newsletters based on categories, user will select the categories for newsletters and then subscribe for them.
mailchimp provides forms embed code for a particular campaign list but i want a single form for multiple campaign lists,sucbscriber can select campaign lists ( categories ) by using checkboxes.
i installed mailchimp module and tries webforms for subscription forms but had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created different mailing lists on mailchimp and forms for all lists and embed them all on my site , but there is no such a feature available on mailchimp to create and embed a single form for all mailing lists.